# Buttons Xna how to add additional arguments

Tags: c#, xna

I've followed tutorials online to make a button class and am slightly stuck. All I want to do is add an argument to the clickedevent e.g.

```
    private void Button_OnPress(object sender, EventArgs e, int number)
    {

    }
```

Whenever I try to then add it as an event to my button I'm running into trouble. e.g.

```
Button.OnPress += new EventHandler(Button_OnPress);
```

Is there something stupid I'm missing. Or is it simply not possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anonymous method:

```
void Button_OnPress(object sender, EventArgs e, int num) { ... }
```

And delegate:

```
Button.OnPress += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
Button_OnPress(sender, e, num); };
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to create a custom EventArgs class.

Comment: @MattDavey I agree, that's basically why they exist.